# date time in php stored

Tags: php, mysql

I have stored date time in mysql from a tutorial as:
2011-02-10 01:21:39

From this, how can I extract the individual elements using php?
Say I just want the year?
or even just the complete date if thats not possible?

Comment: `select year(date) from ` for year and there is mysql function to fetch everything separately

Comment: this has been covered time and time again, almost exactly.

Comment: @nalroff If you're not going to link to a duplicate question, then don't whine - it's not helping. :-)

Comment: @middaparka i would, but there are like 50 of them to the right of this comment. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function. This will convert your date string into a timestamp. Then use [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to pull out the parts you need:

```
$time = strtotime('a string containing some description of the time and date');
$year = date('Y', $time);
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not select the elements from MySQL directly?

```
select year(datefield), month(datefield), day(datefield) from yourtable
```

would return

```
+---------------+
| 2011 | 2 | 10 |
+---------------+
```

of course, if you want to do datemath in PHP, it'd be better to select the date as a UNIX_TIMESTAMP from mysql, which returns time in seconds from Jan 1/1970, which you can feed directly into PHP's date system;

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datefield) ...

$timestamp = mysql_fetch(...)

$date = date($timestamp);
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean `date('Y', strtotime('2011-02-10 01:21:39'));`?

Go with [@Marc's Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960814/date-time-in-php-stored/4960845#4960845) if you are looping through MySQL result set

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`extract`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) function of mysql from within your query like this:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM yourDatefield) AS year,
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM yourDatefield) AS month,
       EXTRACT(DAY FROM yourDatefield) AS day,
       EXTRACT(HOUR FROM yourDatefield) AS hour,
       EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM yourDatefield) AS minute,
       EXTRACT(SECOND FROM yourDatefield) AS second
FROM
       yourTable
```

Check out the [`extract`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) function for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Use php's `date()`.  You can format how ever you need.
[date()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: This does the inverse of what David asked.

Comment: Not really, just not necessarily a complete answer.  Would require `strtotime()` as Alex's answer points out.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php $original = $row['time']; 
$date = date_create($original); 
echo date_format($date, 'Y');?>
```

just replace the $original with your own variable.
definitely check the php `date()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for MySQL

For example, you can:

```
SELECT YEAR(DateColumn) FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

`date($format, strtotime($yourStringFromDB))` see [`PHP docs`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for format strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Dates
WHERE Date LIKE '%02%'
```